# How to add logo in my prestashop template advance footer

Tags: prestashop-1.5

I am using leo sportsshoe free responsive template of prestashop.I have used advance footer module.I need to add my site logo in my advance footer section.How to get it?

Answer (score 0):

{$logo_url} in this variable you will be having the logo image link. you can just use it in where want.

if you want it in your footer means you can call it edit your footer.tpl file in your theme folder.

```
<img src="{$logo_url}" alt="">
```

insert this code where you want to place your image.